# Specify Landscape image for resource iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

when I create a new Imagese in Xcode I see the following screen
[image: missing landscape]

Now I want to specify a separate image for iPad Landscape and iPad Portrait, but there is no such option available.

Offcourse I could do something like

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-landscape.png"];
} else  if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-portrait.png"];
} }
```

But I want to know if there exist any solution inside the interface builder or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't.
 Since the Xcode 6 version you can use size classes from image assets to specify a particular resource.
Unfortunately, iPad uses the same size classes (Regular-Regular) for both orientations.
You can only do that programmatically by asking the status bar orientation and load the asset that you need.